# Making Async HTTP Call with Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a use case where I need to make HTTP calls from my service.I do not want my threads to blocked waiting for the response to come back . How can I do this in SpringWebClient ?
This is how my code looks

```
public void asyncHttp(HTTPMethod method,
                        String url,
                        String body,
                        Map<String, String> headers){

    WebClient.UriSpec<WebClient.RequestBodySpec> uriSpec = webClient.method(method.getMethod());
    WebClient.RequestBodySpec bodySpec = uriSpec.uri(url);
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> headersSpec = bodySpec.bodyValue(body);
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()){
       headersSpec.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    Mono<JsonObject> responseMono =  headersSpec.retrieve().bodyToMono(JsonObject.class);
  }
```

I have two questions here

1. How do I read the response from Mono only after it is completed and parse it. The thread should not wait for the Http Response, once the response is received it should be picked up by a thread.
2. How do I set request specific timeout in the above code ?

Comment: Is your whole application based on Spring WebFlux or you're just using Spring WebClient to make HTTP calls?

Comment: I am just using Spring Webclient to make HTTP calls @2280259

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391267/2462531 It's worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application is not completely reactive and you're using WebClient just to make HTTP calls, you can use [Mono#toFuture()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#toFuture--), [Mono#SubscribeOn()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribeOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-), and [Mono#timeout()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#timeout-java.time.Duration-) for your use case

```
private CompletableFuture<Object> asyncHttpCall(HttpMethod httpMethod, String url, String body, Map<String, String> headers) {

    return WebClient.create(url).method(httpMethod).bodyValue(body).headers(httpHeaders -> headers.forEach(httpHeaders::add))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Object.class)
            // specify timeout
            .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5L))
            // subscribe on a different thread from the given scheduler to avoid blocking as toFuture is a subscriber
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
            // subscribes to the mono and converts it to a completable future
            .toFuture();
}

// execute asyncHttpCall 
asyncHttpCall(HttpMethod.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", "", Collections.emptyMap())
            // consume the response from the CompletableFuture
            .thenAccept(response -> System.out.println("response = " + response));
```

You can

- do multiple other things with the future (check [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)) that `asyncHttpCall` returns.
- configure different Scheduler (check [Schedulers](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html)) in `asyncHttpCall`.
- also use [Mono#doOnSuccess()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnSuccess-java.util.function.Consumer-), [Mono#doOnError()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnError-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Consumer-), etc. with your `Mono` inside `asyncHttpCall`.

Comment: I am not able to return anything as part of Mono.onSuccess() , My code reaches a state where once the output is received   would return it and then it should be stored in cache . Can this be achieved using reactive pattern ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391267/2462531 It's worked for me