# Can I use Spring's WebClient for the synchronous app, and what are the alternatives?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I am creating a Spring Boot MVC application, with Tomcat and JDBC. My app will be an API client, I've learned that I'll need RestTemplate class for API requests. But since Spring 5, RestTemplate is in maintenance mode and will be deprecated in the future.
The alternative is a WebClient class, which is powerful and useful for testing also. But it supports a reactive WebFlux stack.
For example, when I watched this tutorial on how to make tests with WebClient I was very confused:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGK9Hf8cnBw
I must use these Mono and Flux types?

My first question is, can I use WebClient to make a classic servlet-based app (with Tomcat, and JDBC/JPA like I used to)?
If not, what is an alternative to WebClient and RestTemplate?

Comment: Yes, you can and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653680/2280259 may help.

Answer (score 2):

WebClient can be used in synchronous style by blocking at the end for the result like this:

```java
Person project = client.get().uri("/project/{id}", i).retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Project.class)
    .block();

List<Person> projects = client.get().uri("/projects").retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(Project.class)
    .collectList()
    .block();
```

Here we use `block()` to block the stream and get the data out of it. Note that this shouldn’t be used in a reactive environment.

Comment: This will not always work.  If this is executed in a thread that does not allow blocking, even when the server is created via spring web (servlet, non-webflux), it will throw an exception.  I suspect that this is due to the `ReactiveClientHttpConnector` that will execute the request in a thread that cannot be blocked (e.g., `reactor-http-epoll-2`).  In this case, I had to set up the `WebClient` with an apache `HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector`.

Answer (score -1):

This is late but someone might benefit from this.. You can use open feign.. Check it out